# How can I show only "Date and Time" in X-axis in area spine chart in canvasjs?

Tags: html, charts, html5-canvas, canvasjs

I need to show only “Date and Month” in x-axis in Area spine chart. Currently, it shows YYYYMMDD h:i:s but I need to show only DDMM in x-axis.

I need to show only “Date and Month” in x-axis in area spine chart. For e.g Currently, it shows values (2010-10-05, 2012-02-12) values in x-axis but I need to show it (like 5 October, 12 February).

I am using the below code in Area Spine Chart of canvasjs.

```
$( document ).ready(function () {
    var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1",
    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title:{
            text: "Voting Trends"
        },
        axisY: {
            title: "VOTES",
            gridThickness: 0
        },
        data: [{
            type: "splineArea",
            color: "rgba(54,158,173,.7)",
            markerSize: 5,
            xValueFormatString: "",
            dataPoints: [      
                {x: "10 Jul", y: 1, indexLabel: "1"},
                {x: "11 Jul", y: 2, indexLabel: "2"}, 
            ]
        }]
    }); 
    chart1.render();
});
```

This code is not generating any values in the x-axis. Hence the graph does not show exact points on it.
I just need to show these values in x-axis as:
11 July, 12 July, 13 July, etc.
Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CanvasJS supports numeric and date-object in [x-values](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/datapoints/x/) and not string. Passing x-value as date-object and setting [valueFormatString](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisx/valueformatstring/) to "D MMMM" shows axis labels as 5 October, 12 February, etc.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  animationEnabled: true,
  title:{
    text: "Voting Trends"
  },
  axisX: {
    valueFormatString: "D MMMM",
    interval: 1,
    intervalType: "day"
  },
  axisY: {
    title: "VOTES",
    gridThickness: 0
  },
  data: [{
    type: "splineArea",
    color: "rgba(54,158,173,.7)",
    markerSize: 5,
    dataPoints: [      
      {x: new Date("Jul 10 2019"), y: 1, indexLabel: "1"},
      {x: new Date("Jul 11 2019"), y: 2, indexLabel: "2"}, 
    ]
  }]
});

chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 250px; width: 100%;"></div>
```